# Regex to find a word or substring in string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string "https://ccdev-xyzcomm.abc.def.com" or "https://abc--dev.my.zyx.com/

I need to write a regex to determine whether the string contains the word "dev" or not for both the above use case.

I tried the below regex, however, it is working only for the string "https://dev-xyzcomm.abc.def.com"

```
".*\\bdev\\b.*"
```

Can someone help?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "*determine whether the string contains the word "dev" or not*" how about `urlString.contains("dev")`?

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!